# Is it truly necessary to upgrade Tononi's criteria of consciousness in the Integrated Information theory?

Tags: consciousness, neural-network

I am referring specifically to a [very recent paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.1219) by Max Tegmark.
In this paper he proposes 3 more criteria (independence, dynamics, and utility principle) in addition to Tononi's original criteria (information and integration).

I have seen the paper being discussed in [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7024651), [reddit's r/neurophilosophy](http://www.reddit.com/r/neurophilosophy/comments/1uq3c0/14011219_consciousness_as_a_state_of_matter/), and [lesswrong](http://lesswrong.com/lw/jgd/link_consciousness_as_a_state_of_matter_max/), but I think they are mostly light jabs on the actual content of Tegmark's proposal.

Comment: I've published in arxiv but serious papers are actually peer reviewed.

Comment: I agree. But at the very least, the paper was supported (or rather, funded) by NSF.

Comment: i know i published my paper to arxiv because it was deemed unfit for plosone...i know that publishing to arxiv will not help him renew his nsf grant...nsf funding is typically small anyways.

Comment: How can you tell if the paper won't help him renew his nsf? At least, in physics, it is very common to simply publish your work to arxiv.

Comment: For a grant to be renewed by the government it must be based on peer reviewed scientific journal publications or other deliverables.

Comment: Sure, valid point. I get that you are reasonably skeptical to spend your time in reading the "mere arxiv" paper. But I think the paper is just interesting regardless!

Comment: haha no physics never was my strong suite and this is a cog sci question i wouldn't know how to answer anyways. Max is a known cosmologist but his work is not well received by his peers. He does this arxiv pre-pub for attention. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_universe_hypothesis

Comment: Yes, he is a well-known cosmologist. I think the sharp criticism he had, can only mean he is well-received!

Comment: @caseyr547 putting pre-prints on the arXiv is not for attention, but a standard practice in physics, theoretical computer science, and most of mathematics. Now, I am not saying you should treat Tegmark's work seriously (I am not yet familiar with this preprint), but you should not misrepresent the arXiv. The preprint in question came out less than a month ago and could easily be under review somewhere. Not that this even matters, since it is just as easy to publish in 3rd rate journals as upload to the arXiv; papers should be judged on their own quality not based on where they appear.

Comment: @ArtemKaznatcheev Yes I agree your points are fine but Peter Woit said Tegmark was timing his arXiv releases for pole positioning. I think the implication is Tegmark isn't even going to submit to lower quality peer reviewed journals but is going to sell books again. http://www.math.columbia.edu/~woit/wordpress/?p=6551

Comment: @caseyr547 Regarding to the pole positioning case, it should be "Peter Woit said that Tegmark said" (at least he admitted himself, and it was a reasonably thing to do if one had a controversial view while knowing well he could be kicked out of his position, even if he was ready to defend his claim through valid arguments). Isn't it too hasty to conclude that the paper is "yet another Tegmark's 'grandiose nonsense'" before actually reading the content? (or he will just sell books again) I think this paper is more falsifiable in the near future than his level IV claim.

Comment: Identical copy of the question is in http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/9553/is-it-truly-necessary-to-upgrade-tononis-criteria-of-consciousness-in-the-integ

Answer (score 3):

Yes in science all things are constantly upgraded. My main concern is that Tegmark's level of specificity has not been validated through peer review so it may be faulty and not suitable to build future theories.

As Rex Kerr points out in examining Tononi's general criteria I'd consider Tegmark's criteria more specific expositions rather than purely novel information. Further specification beyond Tegmark's work seems to be necessary to define consciousness beyond [primary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_consciousness) like [metacognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacognition).

I don't see how a group of conscious individuals like a society having a [collective consciousness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_consciousness) by sharing information and integrating it into commonality like works of governance, science and art are differentiated from a conscious individual by either Tononi's or Tegmark's current level of specificity.

Edelman, G. M., Tononi, G. (2000). A Universe of Consciousness: How Matter Becomes Imagination. New York: Basic Books

Comment: Thanks, I will just put the bounty on your answer to not waste it. Have been reading stuff, I will put my comments in several days.